# UICollectionView multiple cell(UICollectionViewCell) blinking synchronisation in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a question like in `UICollectionViewCell` I have to blink multiple cell together. But right now if one cell blink then if I select another cell simultaneously than the last item stop blinking and this item start blinking. And I want to blink the LABEL Text.

There are two problems:

1. I want blinking if I even scroll up or down it should not effect or update the cell. It should keep on blinking.
2. Multiple cells blinking

Please I spend a-lot of time already and I have no idea how to resolve.

Tried NOW:
I have tried this now:

It resolve my problem with wrong cell blinking issue. But now multiple cell blinking together how to resolve this I have no idea

```
cell.pricePlate.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3.0];
    cell.pricePlate.alpha = 1;
    cell.pricePlate.textColor = RED;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"cell12 -> %ld  %ld",(long)cell.tag, (long)indexPath.row);
    cell.pricePlate.alpha = 1;
    if(self.cellIdToBlink <= 0)
    {
        cell.pricePlate.textColor = BLACK;
    }
    else
    { 
        cell.pricePlate.textColor = GREEN;
    }
}];
```

Tried Before:
I have tried this before also:

This is inside the cell class. calling like

```
[cell blinking];
```

The issue with this is if I scroll down and come up even with single blinking, it blink and update the wrong cell. with remove the blinking also. I thought its because while perform selector it cannot find out the correct cell. So it blink random.

```
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i<3 ; i++)
{
    if(i == 2)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(animateColor1234:) withObject:color afterDelay:1.5*counter];
        ++counter;
    }
    else{
        [self performSelector:@selector(animateColor1234:) withObject:BLACK afterDelay:1.5*counter];
        ++counter;
    }
}

-(void) animateColor1234:(UIColor *)color {

    [UIView transitionWithView:_pricePlate duration:1 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        _pricePlate.textColor = RED;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished){
            [UIView transitionWithView:_pricePlate duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                _pricePlate.textColor = BLACK;
            }
            completion:^(BOOL done){
                if (done){
                    // Do some program upkeep logic
                    _pricePlate.textColor = color;
                }
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            _pricePlate.textColor = color;
        }
    }];
```

}

last one animation I tested:

CABASE ANIMATION:

I donot know how to animate the text with it. its only for background and foreground

This is how dequeuing cell

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CarCellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(thisItemToBlink) 
    {

        cell.pricePlate.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3.0];
            cell.pricePlate.alpha = 1;
            cell.pricePlate.textColor = RED;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"cell12 -> %ld  %ld",(long)cell.tag, (long)indexPath.row);
            cell.pricePlate.alpha = 1;
            if(self.cellIdToBlink <= 0)
            {
                cell.pricePlate.textColor = BLACK;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.pricePlate.textColor = GREEN;
            }
        }];
    }

}
else
{
    //just change text as not selected item
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: please any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, if you want to do the animation on the label, for infinite times use: 
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {}

Make sure that the reloadData method on the collection view is not called when not necessary.

Also check that the UI operations on the collection view are done on the main thread.

Comment: [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3.0]; 

no i want finate times not infinite times

Comment: i am using same brother... 

check 
                        cell.pricePlate.alpha = 0;
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                              delay:0.1f
                                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                         animations:^{
                                             [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3.0];

Comment: problem is multiple animation synchronization .... like on multiple items if selected.....

Comment: brother i checked it and could be this is the problem :
Make sure that the reloadData method on the collection view is not called when not necessary
now tell me one more thing like when firebase calling on runtime i have to call the reload data and thats why i think it is doing.... how can i resolve this like both things important for me
1) reload data
2) calling firebase

Comment: 2) calling firebase should be first, but it depends if you have pagination or not(eg. you fetch just 20 items at a time and then the next 20 when needed) or all at once. The last one is simpler, and you can call it on viewDidLoad 1) only after the results are received from firebase you should reload the collectionView. You can use reloadItems(at: <#T##[IndexPath]#>) to reload just certain cells, not all of them

Comment: you understand my point now ... and i did work like call came from firestore and then  after every sorting i update the collectionview.... but just imagine if two calls came together one call update all cell and blink.... and then suddenly another call came which will blink and update the color on all cell label... which make it never be synchronize with other cell....

You understand my point? 


check this:

            if(self.cellIdToBlink <= 0)
            {
}

this is the integer which i am setting .... and after every reload data this will decide the blink happen or not

Answer (score 0):

Here is an workaround way.

I assume you use the reuse cell/item now.

The root cause of your problem is the reuse feature.

So, you can try to NOT use the reuse way.

Bellow code is used in UITableView, but I believe you can modify it easy.

Replace your reuse cell code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier"];
```

TO:

```
NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCellNibName" owner:nil options:nil];
if(nibObjs)
  cell = [nibObjs objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: let me try it... dont u thnk it will be expensive?

Comment: Yes, it would be. But for 2 reasons, 1. If UI not very complicated or more than 100 cells, I think it would be fine. 2. Your cell/item need blink or other animation, if use reuse feature that should do other control for stop/start animation, and it maybe expensive.